# MathJax nor working with Vuejs $router.push

Tags: vue.js, mathjax

I'm trying to use MathJax with Vuejs.

It works fine when I just open a page or reload a page. However, it stops working when I do a $router.push method to redirect to another page. In which case the formula is not rendered with MathJax. I am using vue-plugin-load-script for injecting the MathJax library.

I installed vue-plugin-load-scrip:

```
 npm install --save vue-plugin-load-scrip
```

Then I imported it in Main.js

```
import LoadScript from 'vue-plugin-load-script'
Vue.use(LoadScript)
```

And here is what I did in my created() of the page:

```
this.$loadScript("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/latest.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML")
    .then(() => {
      // get my data with Parse Server
      that.text = object.get("text")
    })
    .catch(() => {
      // alert for error
    });
```

in the previous page I used this to push the new page:

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'quizPage', params: {quizId} })
```

I suppose this is possibly a racing problem of some sort but can't find a solution

Thanks very much for any help!
Josh

Comment: We are gonna need some more code, in order to help you with your question.

Comment: This is basically all what I'm doing on this matter, I'll try to update some more

Comment: How about the code where you do a $router.push? Sometimes it helps to create a fiddle with the issue. Isolates the bug.

Comment: Oh yeah forgot about that. Just updated!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that MathJax renders on page load. Vue doesn't really work that way. Fortunately, a kind stranger took the time to create [a vue plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-mathjax) to support it.

Here's [an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nrw4w90o6p) of how it works.